# Format JSON objects in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, json

I have json objects in a notepad(C:\data.txt).There are millions of records I just used one record as an example.But I want to see only data on my notepad like:
1 123-567-9876 TEST1 TEST 717-567-9876 Harrisburg   null US_PA

I dont want paranthesis,etc
Once I get the clean data,plan is to import the data from notepad(say C:\data2.txt) into SQL database.

This is the format of json object.

```
{
    "status":"ok",
      "items":[
  {
     "1":{

        "Work_Phone":"123-567-9876",
        "Name_Part":[
           "TEST1",
           "TEST"
        ],
        "Residence_Phone":"717-567-9876",
        "Mailing_City":"Harrisburg",
        "Mailing_Street_Address_line_1":"",
        "Cell_Phone":null,
        "Mailing_Country_AND_Province_OR_State":"US_PA"

     }
      }
   ]
}
```

Can someone pls help with python code to format this json object and export it to notepad.

Comment: Retagged it for you; PHP is not the same thing as Python.

Comment: Millions of records? How big is the file?

Comment: Only data for example
1 123-567-9876 TEST1 TEST 717-567-9876 Harrisburg null US_PA

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import simplejson as json
```

Then you can open your file and load it into a python-Dictionary:

```
f = file("C:/data.txt","r")
data = json.loads(f.read())
```

But this works only, when the json-objects are stored in an array in your file. So this has to look like this:

```
[{ ... first date ...},
{... second date ...},
...,
{... last date ...}]
```

Then in data there is an array of dictionaries. Now you can write the dates in another file:

```
g = file("output.txt","w")
for d in data:
    for i in items:
        for k in i.keys:
             g.write(... some string build from the parameters ...)
```

If well done the file output.txt contains the lines. In detail it might be difficult becaus each item seems to contain some arrays.